What's the most compact storage method of a Sequence
Say I have n choices of numbers (Say 1 to n) to fill a blank and there are m Blanks, what would be the most "compact" and efficient way to store a particular sequence of them such that all mappings of the stored sequence to the original sequence is unique and vice versa.
It is hard for me to define what compactness means here rigorously so Il give an example:
Say I have a sequence of 5 blanks and 4 numbers (1 to 4) to fill out each blank and I have the sequence 43421 I had treated it as base 5 and converted it into base 10 to make it more "Compact" which results in 2986.
I hope I made it a bit more clear by the example in essence I want the string of numbers to become shorter and such that I can get the original number from the transformed one.

I think you are onto something. The problem here is that you need to be clear/precise what you are trying to optimise/ i.e. what you mean by "compactness". If you are just trying to minimise the number of digits required. Then practically speaking, you only need $1$ digit in base $10^{9999999999}.$ And you can't get more "compact" than one digit, if your definition of "compactness" is "number of digits".

I would want the optimized number to have the standard numbers 0 to 9 so not Anything else like in Hex 1 to F I don't want the A, B, C, D, E, F

Are you aware of Lemma 1.1. of data compression: There does not exist a method for compressing every sequence of numbers into a shorter sequence of numbers in such a way that the original can be uniquely recovered from the compressed version. The proof is  left as an exercise for the reader, though I'm sure we have covered it a few times :-)

What you are talking about is compression, and still an interest of everyone. For example an image in RAW can be simplified to JPEG or GIF and many others with various compression factors. You have to define your question specifically.

@JyrkiLahtonen Oh I see that's a bummer but I did have a hunch it was not possible in the general case but would it be possible for certain sub cases of the values of m and n to optimize it to its theoretical max?

@DavidP This is not a field I'm familiar with But I've been itching to get a definite answer to this question so please do forgive my Naiveness

Spoiler: There are $10^n$ sequences of $n$ digits, and only $10^m$ sequences of $m$ digits. When $m<n$ there is no way to map all those $10^n$ sequences into a universe that only has $10^m$ slots without creating collisions.. A collision means that the original sequence is not always recoverable. In fact, at least 90 per cent of them won't be.

GIF, JPEG, ZIP and such work, because their inputs are not random, but rather images or other data (like text) that has a lot of redundancy. If you give ZIP a totally random file, its length will increase more likely than not. It only works because most of the time its input is an image of something nice, or text/data with some structure.

@JyrkiLahtonen Ya That was fairly trivial I found it out by testing some values I forgot to mention it in the post I want the best ways to compress it when m >n as we can guess that when m = n it cant be compressed any further

@JyrkiLahtonen Oh that's interesting so its like how in some games they instance an object multiple times if its the same instead of rendering it again to save data and computational power

I have a hunch I don't know how valid it is but say m > n and I may not have a definite proof but to my intuition When m = n we cant compress it further so say we do the base operations again and again till we get m = n and stop there, I think if its true it could be proved by induction
